# Results offset by one row when using Index Match with Excel Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

There is data formatted as an Excel Table, Table 3, in Sheet1:

[image]

In Sheet2, there is a subset list of the first field, DuckID. It is required to pull values from the Table 3 by DuckID for a column name within the Table, DateofAscension.

[image]

The formula in B2 uses the INDEX function, with a MATCH to return the row number by DuckID and a MATCH to return column by name:

```
=INDEX(Table3,MATCH(A2,Table3[[#All],[DuckId]],0),MATCH(B1,Table3[#Headers],0))
```

In A2 of Sheet2 is the DuckID 3022. The corresponding DateofAscension of 01/03/2029 is expected in B2. However the formula is returning that for the following row of Table 3, that for DuckID 3090.

What is the error in my formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `[#All],` from `Table3[[#All],[DuckId]]`

```
=INDEX(Table3,MATCH(A2,Table3[DuckId],0),MATCH(B1,Table3[#Headers],0))
```

`[#All]` includes the Header.  So the Match for `3022` is returning `4` to the INDEX which is only looking at the data.